# app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting in nodejs

Tags: node.js, nodejs-server

/app/config/connection.js:14
  if (err) throw err;
           ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1054:14)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at Object. (/app/config/connection.js:13:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:759:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:555:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Answer (score 0):

ECON REFUSED , I think that the port you are using, 3306 is being used by some other applications ( probably an instance of your server that you did not terminate... ) .
It can also be due to firewall blocking NodeJS port access...